# Laravel serve - can't post

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, wamp, passport.js

I'm trying to build an API and wamp is having issues with the OAuth so I am using Laravel Serve. I am using `Laravel 5.3` Passport, each time I `POST`, the response is blank and doesn't respond the correct headers `(Access-Control-Allow-Origin)`. It's also only taking `9MS` to get the response (which should be much longer, close to 600MS with `PUT`). However, if I use `PUT`, it works correctly.

VUE:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;

this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/' + this.post.id + '/comment', formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }, response => {
                // error
            });
```

Middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
   \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
   ],
]
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    // 
    Route::post('/post/{id}/comment, 'Api\Post\CommentController@add');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function add(Request $request, $post_id)
{
   // 
   return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

Spending a lot of time on something that should just work - any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I should also mention that with WAMP, the request is always `Unauthenticated` (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). That is why I am not using WAMP - something about it removing headers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally figured out what was wrong. I was checking my Laravel logs instead of my PHP logs. (Doh!).

Error I was getting:

> **PHP Deprecated:**  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

The solution was too add `always_populate_raw_post_data=-1` to my `php.ini` files:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.23
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.31
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin
```

Restart WAMP services